# Visualize camera_info as a set of four image corner rays emanating from the camera origin in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, camera-info, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this already exists (maybe it was one package among many in a github repo used in a robotics competition a few years ago), but I'm not finding it now.  It would be nice to see where the corners of a camera intersect other geometry or point clouds in rviz while being able to rotate the camera around (as opposed to only looking at rviz geometry from the point of view of the camera with the `Camera` plugin).

A from-scratch implementation could use opencv to get a 3D vectors to each corner (or even generate additional intermediate rays to show the camera distortion), then make an rviz Marker out of them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385531/visualize-camera_info-as-a-set-of-four-image-corner-rays-emanating-from-the-camera-origin-in-rviz?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2021-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know of at least `jsk_rviz_plugins` which can do this: [jsk-visualization.readthedocs.io: CameraInfo](https://jsk-visualization.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jsk_rviz_plugins/plugins/camera_info.html):

[image: camera_info rviz plugin]

There are others I believe, but I'd have to search.

> maybe it was one package among many in a github repo used in a robotics competition a few years ago

you may be remembering Team Vigir's RViz plugins: [team-vigir/vigir_ocs_common](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_ocs_common/tree/7174f9ab6ae5bba1764ceaee7e746df208e1ff12/vigir_ocs_rviz_plugins). But from [this](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_ocs_common/tree/7174f9ab6ae5bba1764ceaee7e746df208e1ff12/vigir_ocs_rviz_plugins/vigir_ocs_rviz_plugin_camera_frustum_display_custom), I get the impression it's basically the `jsk_rviz_plugins` plugin with some configuration options added.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1